# Почему-то файл moment.js не работает при упаковке с помощью webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, momentjs

```
const path = require('path'); // Импортируем модуль "path" для работы с путями файлов
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry:
    {
        app: ['./src/Draw-io-plugin-indusoft.js'
            , './src/macroFormatter.js'
            , './src/arrayFunctions.js'
            , './src/numberFormatter.js'
            , './src/stringFunctions.js'
            , './src/moment.js'
           
    


        ], // Точка входа для сборки проекта
       
    },
  output: {
    filename: 'Draw-io-plugin-indusoft-library.js', // Имя выходного файла сборки
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'output') // Путь для выходного файла сборки
  },
  };
```

это код webpack.config.js moment.js пакуется, но не работает при подключении, если подключать отдельно, то работает